# Можно ли, используя mikrotik api, подключаться к оборудованию по mac адресу, как в винбоксе?

Tags: mikrotik

Если на микротике нет ip, зная мак можно ли подключаться по маку через api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Официально - нельзя, API доступно только по IP. Максимум, что можно сделать по MAC, это подключиться через MAC Telnet из терминала другого MikroTik при помощи следующей команды:

```
/tool mac-telnet 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

где `00:00:00:00:00:00` это MAC адрес устройства, к которому нужно подключиться.

Сам протокол проприетарный, но если есть время и желание заморочиться, то [вот здесь](https://omniflux.com/devel/mikrotik/Mikrotik_MAC_Telnet_Procotol.txt) есть информация о протоколе, а [вот здесь](https://github.com/haakonnessjoen/MAC-Telnet/) - реализация для POSIX. Но в любом случае это Telnet подключение, а не API, со всеми вытекающими из этого нюансами и ограничениями.